# Why does using footer LoadStateAdapter with RecyclerView and Paging 3 makes list open at wrong layout position?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-paging, android-paging-3

The problem is quite simple: when I use an LoadStateAdapter (as a footer adapter), the RecyclerView opens the list from the wrong position. If I don't use `adapter.withLoadStateFooter(footerAdapter)` then there is no problem and the list behaves normally. That is, it opens from the beginning of the list.

I have tried different paging configs, using both header- and footer adapter and variation of custom loadStateListener implementations.

Repo

```
fun newPagingDataFlow(search: String? = null): Flow<PagingData<Item>> {
    val pagingConfig = PagingConfig(
        pageSize = 30,
        enablePlaceholders = true
    )

    // ...

    return Pager(
        config = pagingConfig,
        remoteMediator = remoteMediator
    ) {
        dao.getPagingSource(search)
    }.flow
}
```

View

```
val footerAdapter = SomeLoadStateAdapter(layoutInflater)
binding.recyclerView.apply {
    adapter = someAdapter.withLoadStateFooter(footerAdapter)
    layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
    setHasFixedSize(true)
}
```

[Link to gif where LoadStateAdapters are used as header and footer, similar problem with only footer adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KlJm.gif)

Comment: I encountered this exact issue.  Whenever I use with withLoadStateFooter(), the RecyclerView's initial position starts at middle of the page instead of first item in the list.  Did you ever figure out the root cause or know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I met similar issue before. In my case, I need footer always visible so I set `displayLoadStateAsItem` in `LoadStateAdapter` always `true`.
There's two paging adapter that need the the same LoadStateAdapter.

I noticed that one of them can work as expect, but I saw the other one caused the `RecyclerView` start at the third item. Then, just like what you have done, I tried many ways to solve it, in the end, I found this can let my case work normally.

I'm not sure what do you want to do with footer. Hope this can help you or at least help you figure out the answer.

In `LoadStateAdapter`

```
override fun displayLoadStateAsItem(loadState: LoadState): Boolean {
  return loadState is LoadState.NotLoading && loadState.endOfPaginationReached
}
```